# How do I change constraints in a dojo DateTextBox dynamically?

Tags: date, textbox, dojo, constraints

I tried to do this:

```
dojo.mixin(endDate.constraints, {min: new Date(2009,09,14)});
```

But as a result I got this:

```
min    Wed Oct 14 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CET)
```

??? It always adds one month! Is this a bug?

But what I actually want to do is something like this:

```
dojo.mixin(endDate.constraints, {min: dijit.byId("beginDate").date});
```

This results in:

```
min    undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben, as for the second part of your question, there is no date property on a [DateTextBox](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dijit.form.DateTextBox).  What you want is the value attribute

```
dijit.byId("beginDate").attr("value")
```

which does return a Date object.

Comment: by the way, 09 is octal, though browsers seem to pretend it's decimal.  Make sure to avoid leading zeros in unquoted numbers.

Comment: or pass in a base when running passe int:  parseInt('08',10) vs. parseInt('08')

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug - it's a feature! And it's not a feature of Dojo, but [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date):

> Integer value representing the month,
>   beginning with 0 for January to 11 for
>   December.

In order to debug that error, just use FireBug to see 1) what `dijit.byId("beginDate").date` returns - a string or a date object?, 2) if it's a string, is it correctly formatted; can `new Date` parse it?, etc...